# Sencha touch - render form field as non-input

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs

I have this view for sending a message:

[image]

However, I don't want the 'to' field to be an input field, i just want to display jamie as text.

My form items:

```
      {
        name : 'to',
        label: 'To',
        xtype: 'field',
        value: 'jamie',
        required: false
      },
      {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        name : 'subject',
        label: 'Subject',
        placeHolder: 'Subject...'
      },
      {
        xtype: 'textareafield',
        name : 'message',
        label: 'Message', 
        placeHolder: 'Message...'
      }
```

I've looked at the API docs and i can't find a way to do it. I suppose it's trivial.

EDIT: I know i  can set it as disabled. But i really don't want it to be an input field.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the CSS style as follows:

```
.thouShaltNotEdit div input{color:#567803; text-decoration:underline;}
```

Then in your javascript:

```
TextFieldName = new Ext.Text ({
...
disabledCls : 'thouShaltNotEdit',
disabled: true
...
})
```

The problem is Sencha applies some additional transparency effect after the fact, I've never been able to trace it down. The next best thing for me is setting the color of the 'thouShaltNotEdit' class to a color that looks good with the transparancy effect, as done above.

I've head of an undocumented '`readOnly`' property as well, might be worth investigating if the above doesn't suite your needs.

#### Additional Option

You can also just set the html of your ext object in a slightly more hackish way as follows:
CSS:

```
.x-input-text-not-a-field{height:40px; padding:5px; background-color:white; display:block;}
```

JavaScript:

```
var txtEmail = new Ext.form.Text({
        html:'<div class="x-form-label"><span>E-mail</span></div>'
            + '<div class="x-form-field-container"><span class="x-input-text-not-a-field">Jamie</span></div>' 
    });
```

Some additional CSS tweaking may be required, but that's the general idea to make it NOT an input field. PS: Setting the 'html' property basically wipes out all of the objects settings.

Comment: thanks your response. "thouShaltNotEdit". heh this made me laugh.... however, I really don't want it to be any type of input field. I'd rather have a span element (which is styled the same as in the screenshot) with 'jamie' as the content....

Comment: I just added an additional option above

Answer (score 1):

```
Ext.form.LabelField = function(config) {
    Ext.form.LabelField.superclass.constructor.call(this, config);
};


Ext.extend (Ext.form.LabelField, Ext.form.Field,{
    isField: true,
    value: '',
    renderSelectors: {fieldEl: '.x-form-labelfield'},
    renderTpl: [
       '<tpl if="label">',
       '<div class="x-form-label x-form-title"><span>{label}</span></div>',
       '</tpl>',
       '<div class="x-form-label x-form-labelfield"><span>{value}</span></div>',
    ],
    setValue:function(val) {
        this.value = val;
        if (this.rendered) {
           this.fieldEl.update('<span>' + val + '</span>');
        }
        return this;
    },
});

Ext.reg('labelfield', Ext.form.LabelField);
```

In Formpanel:

```
labelTo = {
    xtype: 'labelfield',
    name: 'LabelName',
    cls: 'label-field',
    itemId: 'LabelName',
    label: 'To:',
    value: 'Jame'
};
```